# Publishing PCL *Coefficients

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I start the publisher

> ```
>   pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("projected_inliers", 1);
> ```

I run ransac using the cylinder model

```
     .
```

> pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr
> coefficients2 (new
> pcl::ModelCoefficients);

```
     .
     .
```

> seg.segment (*inliers2,
> *coefficients2);

I print the coefficients fine to the terminal.

> std::cerr << "Cylinder coefficients: "
> << *coefficients2 << std::endl;
>
> pubCyl.publish (*coefficients2);

But I can't seem to publish the coefficients2 successfully. It doesn't throw any errors but when I run rostopic echo /Cylinder_coef it slows my computer down to a stall if I don't end it rather quickly... I'm not sure if this has to do with it being a pointer and it somehow breaks or if I'm missing something else.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51144/publishing-pcl-*coefficients/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So figured out a solution.  Very simple mistake on my part, the ROS publisher needed a string so I just did the following,

std_msgs::String msg;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << *coefficients2;
msg.data = ss.str();
pubCyl.publish(msg);

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0